# C# LINQ получить уникальные значения по определенному полю

Tags: c#, linq

Из БД получаю список объектов `Server`, у `Server` одно из полей называется `Id`.

```
public class Server 
{
    public int Id { get;set; }
    public string Name { get;set; }
    ....
}
```

Есть таблица `ServerTags`, в которой хранятся теги для каждого `Server.Id`, у `Server.Id` может быть несколько тегов

Таблица:

```
|ServerId|TagId|TagName|
```

Мне требуется:

1. Получить лист нужных мне `Server` - ОК, получаю
2. Выбрать из таблицы `ServerTags` все теги по каждому `Server.Id` и сгруппировать
   по `TagId` без потери остальных полей и их значений - грубо говоря оставить только уникальные значения `TagId`

Использую в данный момент такое решение:

```
List<Server> servers;
using (ServerContext db = new ServerContext())
{
    servers = db.Servers.Where(e => e.Status == ServerStatus.Active).ToList();
}

using (TagContext db = new TagContext())
{
    List<ServerTag> tags = servers.Select(server => db.ServerTags
        .First(e => e.ServerId == server.Id)).ToList()
        .GroupBy(x => x.TagId).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();
}
```

Вроде бы работает, но при выборке выбирается только 1 тег по каждому серверу, остальные тупо не выбираются, как сделать правильно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого подходит метод `SelectMany`, пример:

```
List<Server> servers;
using (ServerContext db = new ServerContext())
{
    servers = db.Servers.Where(e => e.Status == ServerStatus.Active).ToList();
}

using (TagContext db = new TagContext())
{
    List<ServerTag> tags = servers.SelectMany(server => db.ServerTags.Where(e => e.ServerId == server.Id))
                                  .GroupBy(x => x.TagId)
                                  .Select(x => x.First())
                                  .ToList();
}
```

Comment: работает, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

Используй join, что-то типа такого, пишу сходу без проверки:

```
var query = from servers in db.Servers
join serverTags in db.ServerTags on servers.Id equals serverTags.ServerId
orderby servers.Id
select new
{
 Name = servers.Name,
 Id = servers.Id,
 TagName= serverTags.TagName,
 TagId = serverTags.TagId
};

foreach (var item in query)
{
 // обработка выборки
}
```